Plot3D for a problem where the initial value of the independent variable is a parameter in ParametricNDSolve
I would like to obtain a Plot3D from a ParametricNDSolve routine; I encounter a problem similar to
Initial time as parameter in ParametricNDSolve,
ParametricNDSolve with variable initial conditions
However, my system is non-autonomous (the independent variable appears explicity in the ODE of 8th order as well as in the 8 boundary conditions) and rather complex, so I'd prefer not to perform any variable change. Moreover, I would need to finally obtain a 3Dplot in terms of the independent variable (r) and the parameter (rri), so tables are not an option. I report the code below:
eq=r^4 U[r]+((-76.05285673543112 +6.337738061285926 r^2) U'[r])/r+(76.05285673543112` -6.337738061285926 r^2) U''[r]+r (1.378122128212441 r^3+(-57.03964255157334 +12.675476122571853 r^2) Derivative[3][U][r]+(31.688690306429635 r+6.337738061285926 r^3) Derivative[4][U][r]+23.766517729822226 Derivative[5][U][r]-24.558734987482968 r^2 Derivative[5][U][r]-23.766517729822226 r Derivative[6][U][r]-12.279367493741484 r^3 Derivative[6][U][r]+11.883258864911113 r^2 Derivative[7][U][r]+5.9416294324555565 r^3 Derivative[8][U][r])==0;

bc1=((3+rri) U'[rri])/rri+rri ((3+2 rri) Derivative[3][U][rri]+(-2+rri) rri Derivative[4][U][rri]-(1.875 +1.875 rri+rri^2) Derivative[5][U][rri]-0.9375 (-2+rri) rri Derivative[6][U][rri])==(3+rri) U''[rri]+rri^3 (-0.217447 -0.9375 Derivative[3][U][rri]);

bc2=12.021653169392291 +0.2124992124992125 U'[3.80952]+17.5963252608 Derivative[3][U][3.80952]+84.31032571016141 Derivative[4][U][3.80952]+35.21746051736141 Derivative[5][U][3.80952]-79.04093035327632 Derivative[6][U][3.80952]-51.83010042127633 Derivative[7][U][3.80952]==0.80952 U''[3.80952];

bc3=U''[rri]==Derivative[3][U][rri];

bc4=U''[3.80952]+Derivative[3][U][3.80952]==0;

bc5=U[3.80952]==0;

bc6=(0.25 U'[rri])/rri+U''[rri]-0.9375 Derivative[4][U][rri]==0.157785;

bc7=U[rri]==0;

bc8=U'[rri]==0;

sysNI=eq&&bc1&&bc2&&bc3&&bc4&&bc5&&bc6&&bc7&&bc8;

sI=ParametricNDSolve[sysNI,U,{r,rri,3.8},{rri}];

plI=Plot3D[U[rri][r]/.sI,{r,0.5,3.8},{rri,0.29,1.42},PlotRange->All,ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[.8*z]],PlotLegends->BarLegend[{Hue,{min,max}}],BoundaryStyle->None,PlotTheme->"Detailed"]

I analogously obtain the message
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable U'.

Are there any recent developments in the newer versions of Mathematica that have allowed to overcome this issue? Or any other options to obtain my plot in your opinion?

what does (U^(3))[3.80952] mean? And it will be more clear to the reader to write each ode on its own, write the IC on its own, and then use these variables in the call to NDSolve. Why do you have to write everything in one very long line for? If you break things apart it makes it easier to see and to find problems in the code.

They are indicating the 3rd, 4th, 5th, ... derivative of U so I've kept them in the original format to avoid confusion with powers of U. (U^(3))[3.80952] indicates the 3rd derivative of U at the other (fixed) boundary extremum. I have now separated the equation and the boundary conditions into different lines.

The the 3rd,  5th derivative of U Should be Derivative[3][U], Derivative[5][U] etc.

Define a function sol[rri].
Clear["Global`*"];
sol[rri_] := 
  Module[{eq, bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, bc5, bc6, bc7, bc8, sysNI, sI}, 
   eq = r^4 U[
        r] + ((-76.05285673543112 + 6.337738061285926 r^2) U'[r])/
       r + (76.05285673543112` - 6.337738061285926 r^2) U''[r] + 
      r (1.378122128212441 r^3 + (-57.03964255157334 + 
            12.675476122571853 r^2) Derivative[3][U][
           r] + (31.688690306429635 r + 
            6.337738061285926 r^3) Derivative[4][U][r] + 
         23.766517729822226 Derivative[5][U][r] - 
         24.558734987482968 r^2 Derivative[5][U][r] - 
         23.766517729822226 r Derivative[6][U][r] - 
         12.279367493741484 r^3 Derivative[6][U][r] + 
         11.883258864911113 r^2 Derivative[7][U][r] + 
         5.9416294324555565 r^3 Derivative[8][U][r]) == 0;
   bc1 = ((3 + rri) U'[rri])/rri + 
      rri ((3 + 2 rri) Derivative[3][U][
           rri] + (-2 + rri) rri Derivative[4][U][
           rri] - (1.875 + 1.875 rri + rri^2) Derivative[5][U][rri] - 
         0.9375 (-2 + rri) rri Derivative[6][U][rri]) == (3 + rri) U''[
        rri] + rri^3 (-0.217447 - 0.9375 Derivative[3][U][rri]);
   
   bc2 = 
    12.021653169392291 + 0.2124992124992125 U'[3.80952] + 
      17.5963252608 Derivative[3][U][3.80952] + 
      84.31032571016141 Derivative[4][U][3.80952] + 
      35.21746051736141 Derivative[5][U][3.80952] - 
      79.04093035327632 Derivative[6][U][3.80952] - 
      51.83010042127633 Derivative[7][U][3.80952] == 
     0.80952 U''[3.80952];
   
   bc3 = U''[rri] == Derivative[3][U][rri];
   
   bc4 = U''[3.80952] + Derivative[3][U][3.80952] == 0;
   
   bc5 = U[3.80952] == 0;
   
   bc6 = (0.25 U'[rri])/rri + U''[rri] - 
      0.9375 Derivative[4][U][rri] == 0.157785;
   
   bc7 = U[rri] == 0;
   
   bc8 = U'[rri] == 0;
   
   sysNI = 
    eq && bc1 && bc2 && bc3 && bc4 && bc5 && bc6 && bc7 && bc8;
   
   sI = NDSolve[sysNI, U, {r, rri, 3.8}]];



Plot the solution by Plot and Table.

Table[Plot[
   U[s] /. sol[rri][[1]] // Evaluate, {s, rri, 3.8}], {rri, .1, 
   3.7, .1}] // Show



Plot the solution by Plot3D.

f[s_, rri_] := U[s] /. sol[rri][[1]];
Plot3D[f[s, rri], {rri, .2, 3.7}, {s, rri, 3.8}]


